# Is there a way to optimise this query which involves unpacking json?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a query which almost returns the data that I need but I can't quite work out. I am bit rusty with SQL, but basically I'm trying to get a row structure with:

- username, color, codeId, actionDate

With the conditions:

- row matches `email`
- their latest `actionDate` (there are many, so I want newest) for `enabled` action is shown. If no `actionDate` is available for `enabled` action I show null

  The table `actions` looks bit like this:

```
    ID      email               action          jsonData                                                                actionDate
    1       bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "user.a@example.com", "Delta": null}      2019-01-05
    4       bob@example.com     enabledForce    {"Color": "Blue", "CodeId": "004", "Username": "user.a@example.com"}    2019-01-20
    5       bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "user.b@example.com", "Delta": null}      2019-01-05
    6       bob@example.com     enabledForce    {"Color": "Blue", "CodeId": "009", "Username": "user.b@example.com"}    2019-01-14
    23      bob@example.com     enabledForce    {"Color": "Red", "Username": "user"}                                    2019-01-06
    56      bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "user.b@example.com", "Delta": null}      2019-01-05
    443     bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "user.a@example.com", "Delta": null}      2019-01-05
    2356    bob@example.com     enabledForce    {"Color": "Blue", "CodeId": "004", "Username": "user.a@example.com"}    2019-01-23
    4353    bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "user.a.b@example.com", "Delta": null}    2019-01-19
    4535    bob@example.com     enabledForce    {"Color": "Blue", "CodeId": "005", "Username": "user.a.b@example.com"}  2019-01-23
    5643    bob@example.com     enabled         {"Color": "Blue", "Username": "anotheruser@google.com", "Delta": null}  2019-08-03
```

Here is my query that I tried:

```
select username,
       color,
       codeId,
       min(DateEnabled),
from (
      SELECT distinct 
             jsonData ->> 'username' AS username,
             jsonData ->> 'color'    AS color,
             jsonData ->> 'codeId'    AS codeId,
             min(CASE
                 WHEN action_name = 'enabled'
                     THEN actionDate
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) AS DateEnabled,
             jsonData
       FROM actions
           where jsonData ->> 'Username' is not null
           and email = 'bob@example.com'
           and (action_name = 'enabled' or
                action_name = 'enabledForce')
           group by username, actionDate, jsonData 
   ) as inquery
   group by username, orgcolorype, codeId
```

This returns data that looks like this:

```
username               color   codeId   DateEnabled
-------------------------------------------------------------------
user                    Red             2019-01-06
user.a@example.com      Blue    004     2019-01-05
user.a@example.com      Blue        
user.a.b@example.com    Blue    005     2019-01-19
user.a.b@example.com    Blue        
user.b@example.com      Blue    009     2019-01-05
user.b@example.com      Blue        
anotheruser@google.com  Blue
```

What I want is above, but take the username which has a date if available, otherwise default to null:

```
user                    Red             2019-01-06
user.a@example.com      Blue    004     2019-01-05
user.a.b@example.com    Blue    005     2019-01-19
user.b@example.com      Blue    009     2019-01-05  
anotheruser@google.com  Blue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
action_name = 'enabled' OR action_name = 'enabledForce'
```

to

```
action_name IN ('enabled', 'enabledForce')
```

and create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON actions (email, action_name)
   WHERE jsonData ->> 'Username' IS NOT NULL;
```

To always get the row with the latest `dateenabled`, use a construct like this:

```
select DISTINCT ON(username)
       username,
       color,
       codeId,
       DateEnabled
/* your FROM */
ORDER BY dateenabled DESC NULLS LAST,
         color,
         codeid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can see this will certainly help with performance! However, I am still not getting the result that I want. I only need the latest `DateEnabled` (if multiple) or fall back to null if its the only one available. Do you have any ideas how I could achieve this? Once again, thank you!

Comment: I forgot that requirement. I have extended the answer.

Comment: I think that's done it! I was not aware of that `order by` constructs - many thanks Laurenz!